# How to let you change the order of products?

Tags: mysql, database-design, best-practices

On the database there is this table:

**products:**

| id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product 1 | 1 |
| 2 | product 2 | 2 |
| 3 | product 3 | 2 |
| 4 | product 4 | 1 |
| 5 | product 5 | 1 |
| 6 | product 6 | 1 |
| 7 | product 7 | 2 |

the select to extract them is:

```sql
select * from products order by id
```

This select sorts by id, so I will get this result:

[image: sort by id]

But now they want that the administrator can change the order, so **he can set a custom order**. For example this:

[image: sort by custom order]

As you can see it's a custom order, it doesn't sort by id but it is decided by the administrator, and I want that this order remains for every user, so it shouldn't be lost when page is refreshed.

Which is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But now they want that the administrator can change the order, so **he can set a custom order**.
>
> Which is the best way to implement this?

You would want to add another column to your `products` table called `sortOrder`. It would be a numerical column, like an `INT`.

You can then add a sort order number for each `product` in the order you want them to sort. You should space the numbers apart in case you need to insert any `products` in between two existing `products` sort order. E.g. by 10s or 100s.

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see it's a custom order, it doesn't sort by id but it is
> decided by the administrator, and I want that this order remains for
> every user, so it shouldn't be lost when page is refreshed.

There is another way . You can use [FIELD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function in the order by .

```
select p.id,
       p.name,
       p.type
from products p 
order by field (id,5,1,6,4,3,7,2);
```

Result:

```
id  name       type
5   product 5   1
1   product 1   1
6   product 6   1
4   product 4   1
3   product 3   2
7   product 7   2
2   product 2   2
```

Now the order pattern can be changed by the administrator.

I can't think of an automatically way to create order patterns.

Answer (score 0):

if such kind of select is frequent， the best way is to add a column that can satisfy your requirement (an int column and set the number that you need), and *add an index on it*,
to make sure you don't need to "sort file" every time you need.